# Trouble with lsyncd on Unix server running Centos

Tags: unix, centos, synchronization, real-time, lsyncd

I am trying to setup a simple lsyncd example on my Unix server running Centos.  I am following this article.  https://www.unixmen.com/how-to-sync-files-with-lsyncd/

I am sure I have followed the instructions correctly, however it is not syncing nor logging.  Can anyone help me out with this?  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the initial tutorial that I posted here had some errors.  I found and followed this article instead and it worked perfectly.

https://ostechnix.com/synchronize-local-remote-directories-linux/